# Changed site title by SEO plugin!

Tags: seo, title, name

If the plug-in is disabled. The site name is displayed.

But enabled, the site name changes.And the number 41 is displayed ?!

[image]

My SEO plugin is Yoast seo.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the settings of the Yoast plugin when it is enabled? What does the plugin setting for title tag say?

Comment: @HenryVisotski I checked everything. Everywhere my site name is correctly inserted.

Comment: @HenryVisotski for example: Site Title is "فونل", Site Identity is "فونل", Seo configurator Wizard > Title settings > فونل !

Comment: Hmmm... how does the site title appear in search pages themselves when the plugin is enabled? What about the source code? Does the title tag in page source appear as “41”?

Comment: @HenryVisotski It happened yesterday and the original name is still listed in the search results. Page names are displayed correctly! Only the homepage has changed to 41?

Comment: @HenryVisotski I added a code image to my question.

Comment: I went to your site, and I see what you're saying. Thank you for adding the screenshot too. Not sure what the issue is. Yoast has an article that may help you troubleshoot: https://kb.yoast.com/kb/the-seo-title-output-for-the-plugin-doesnt-work-as-expected/ - good luck!

Comment: @HenryVisotski I found the answer. Seo > Search Appearance > General > Homepage & Front page > editing the front page itself :) Thanks for your help too

Comment: Awesome - glad it’s resolved!

Comment: @tooraj You should add that as an answer (and later _accept_ it) to help other readers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you say you found a solution without getting any answers here.